# Finding smallest Constant for an inequality.

Tags: inequality

Let $x$ and $y$ belong to the interval $(0, 1]$ and suppose $x < y$.

Doing some computational work, I'm always able to find a constant $C > 0$ such that the following inequality holds for all $x$ and $y$ as given above.

$\text{Min}\{ 2y, (1 + \frac{1}{x})(y-x) \} \leq C \sqrt{y - x} $

My question is, what is the least possible constant $C > 0$ such that this holds, and could you exhibit a good method for finding it?

Comment: Maybe you can find the minima of $2y/\sqrt{y-x}$ and $(1+1/x)(y-x)/\sqrt{y-x}$ within $(0,1]^2$ separately and choose the smaller of the two, that should give you $C$, I think

Comment: Find  the relation connecting $x$ and $y$ such that $2y=(1+1/x)(y-x)$. Solve for $y.$ Then divide by $\sqrt{y-x}$. You get a function of $x.$ Maximize that function in the interval $(0,1].$